# Creating a NICE collapsible menu

Tags: routes

Does anyone know how to create an expandable menu like they have on this page?

http://www.geofunders.org/events/geocc/registration

Note: scroll down to see the menu under 'Conference Policies'. First one is 'Participant Eligibility'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Molot ok, that's fine, I understand. Now that I think about it you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just simple jQuery.

[SEE THIS EXAMPLE I MADE FOR YOU](http://jsfiddle.net/LaSsr/615/)

**In Drupal to use jQuery you need to wrap it in**

```
(function ($) {

    //code goes here

})(jQuery);
```

so your code should look like this

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".button").click(function () {
             $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
         });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Remember that you need to add to your css `.content { display: none; }` OR you could do it with jquery

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".content").css("display", "none");
         $(".button").click(function () {
             $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
         });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**Note:** this code works assuming there are no divs in between your `.button` and `.content`. If there are divs in between them, you might need to modify the slideToggle line.

Comment: PS: if u want to change the speed, add a number to slideToggle. EX: .slideToggle(8000); will take 8 seconds to open or close.

Comment: oh, very interesting...thank you. The default seems fine now, but good to know in case my client asks for it.